# Write hebrew text to pdf using itextpdf

Tags: itext, aem, hebrew

I'm  trying to write Hebrew characters to a PDF.

I created HTML in the servlet by appending to a string buffer.

Then passing the same to xmlworkerhelper.

Also registered the arial.ttf, arialuni.ttf and arialbold.ttf fonts using XMLWorkerFontProvider and using the registered fonts  in xmlworkerhelper.

Used the below fonts for registering arial.ttf, ArialBold.ttf, arialuni.ttf;

Any solutions for this issue will be very helpful. Let me know if more details required.

Below is the snippet.

```
XMLWorkerFontProvider fontImp = new XMLWorkerFontProvider();
fontImp.register(arial);
fontImp.register(arialbold);
fontImp.register(arialuni);
byte[] byte6=PDFtext.toString().getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
String bufferfinalPDF=new String(byte6, "UTF-8");
XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, new ByteArrayInputStream(bufferfinalPDF.getBytes(Charset.forName(baseFont))),null,Charset.forName(baseFont),fontImp);
```

Solution or a suggestion on this is very helpful.

Comment: A question about converting Hebrew HTML to PDF using XML Worker was answered a week ago: [Can't set RTL direction for Hebrew letters while converting from \*.xhtml to \*.pdf by using iText library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30847907/cant-set-rtl-direction-for-hebrew-letters-while-converting-from-xhtml-to-pd) You don't show any HTML in your question. Did you define the *direction* of the Hebrew text as RTL?

Comment: Also I am not able to change the directions to RTL. I m using 5.4.4. But the link mentioned helps for itextpdf version 5.5.5. Without upgrading the itextpdf version, any suggestions is very helpful.

Comment: The `dir` attribute was introduced in [iText 5.5.4](http://itextpdf.com/changelog/554), so you'll have to upgrade.

Comment: Any work around for this without using dir. Tried PdfWriter.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL). But still not able to change the direction

Comment: No, there's no other workaround. Why would it be a problem to upgrade from 5.4.4 to 5.5.6?

Comment: We have aligned position of the texts and some images using table and inline styles in 5.4.4. 
But when I try running using the same HTML using 5.5.6, there is difference in the positioning of the texts.

The same HTML content with inline styles as input for itextpdf 5.4.4 and for itextpdf 5.5.6 have difference in the pdf display, means positioning of text start varies. Wondering if any functionalities or styles beings no longer used in 5.5.6.

Comment: That would be a question for support at iText Software. As you are using iText 5, chances are that you're a paying customer (unless you fully comply with the AGPL in which case I'd like to see your entire source code). Did you submit a ticket to the issue tracker at iText Software.

Comment: It solved. Not sure the reason, may be some alignment. Thanks

Comment: Romanian characters like "ț" and "ș" displaying as ?. Any fonts to be registered to resolve this. Any suggestion on this is very helpful.